# i wanted to run sqlite code in vs code but it shows sqlite is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-code

C:\Users\acer\djnago>npm install sqlite

added 1 package, and audited 124 packages in 13s

3 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
C:\Users\acer\djnago>sqlite flights.sql
'sqlite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm` only installs the required libraries for Node.js.  You need to install the SQLite tools for Windows from the [official website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).